# Mention in embed

Tags: discord.js

Is it possible to mention someone in an embed so that they receive a notification?

When I try this code:

```
message.channel.send({ embed: { fields: [
{
    name: "test",
    value: args[0]
}
]}});
```

with `args[0]` being a mention, the mention in the embed is well displayed (clickable, ...) but the user mentioned doesn't get pinged.

If I ping myself using the command (and mentioning myself in the argument) I'm not pinged and the message isn't displayed as usual when being mentioned (yellow background, ...) but I get my profile info if I click on the *@...* in the message.

Comment: `plainText: member` you have a field on embed which you can use to mention a user

Comment: I want to format a table that contains mentions. Normal font makes that quite hard since it's not monospace while inline embed makes table easy to do. I'll remember the `plainText` for if I need to though. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly you can't make a mention notify the mentioned user by using an Embed, a possible workaround is by having the mention in the message content, instead of the embed. For example:

```js
message.channel.send(args[0], { embed: { fields: [
{
    name: "test",
    value: args[0]
}
]}});
```

This is a limitation of the Discord API itself.